# Building a tool similar to the JQuery UI custom download Builder

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

All,

How would you build a tool similar to the JQuery UI custom download builder (at http://jqueryui.com/download)? It uses a series of checkboxes that select and include individual script components into a custom code bundle, which can then be downloaded.

The use case I'm thinking of is for custom building a CSS framework bundle from several component CSS files, but it could be used to select and assemble any kind of scripts.

Would you use JQuery/AJAX client-side to load and assemble each component script when a checkbox is checked? Or perhaps post a query to the server which would assemble the scripts and return the bundle through AJAX? How would you assemble and store the code components into one structure which could then be downloaded?

Thanks for your ideas,
-NorthK

Answer (score 3):

The download button is a form submit.  That indicates that it is being assembled server side, in the language of their choice, packaged, and made available for download.  Because of the nature of jQuery files, it would be trivial to have either individual files or code snippets that were assembled server side into a zipped file that could be then sent to the browser as a download....no compiling, etc necessary.

In your case, I would hope that the file count would be kept relatively to a minimum, because downloading a large number of css files adds overhead to sites.  Personally, I'd prefer one large, minified CSS file if I was using your framework.  Even better could be one that I could load via CDN and just toggle options in the download URL.....no download required.

Answer (score 0):

I just created [DownloadBuilder.js](http://gregfranko.com/DownloadBuilder.js/), a JavaScript library that uses the HTML5 Filesystem API to create concatenated single file custom builds for front-end projects.  Check it out and see if it would work as a solution for you.

Comment: Looked good, but seem your lib is not supporting require/dependent option

Comment: I'm currently in the process of supporting Require.js builds with it, which would make handling inner dependencies much easier.